# Python : Passing parameters by reference down chain

Tags: python, quart

I am trying to pass a variable (MySQL connection class instance) down into a method and then into a class, the issue is that it needs to be done 'by reference' as the main class can change the value.  The variable in the final class does not update though:

application:

```
def __init__(self, quart_instance) -> None:
    self._db_object : mysql_connection.MySQLConnection = None

def initialise_app(self):
    self.view_blueprint = health_view.create_blueprint(self._db_object)
```

Health View:

```
def create_blueprint(db_connector : mysql_connection.MySQLConnection):
    view = View(db_connector)

class View:

    def __init__(self, db_connector):
        self._db_connector = db_connector
```

When the application performs the database connection in the background in the application I was expecting self._db_connector in the view to update.  Any help would be appreciated as I am very confused.

Comment: You can't pass variables by reference in Python. What you do is passing references by value, but the word "reference" means a different thing there.

Comment: @molbdnilo You can pass parameters into a method that changes them, the change is reflected in the code calling it.  Would I be forced to either have a global (which isn't nice) or implement a form of singleton?

Comment: Yes, that's because you pass a reference as a value. When you "pass by reference" you can also *assign* to the variable passed in, not just mutate the object that your argument refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse changing the state of an object with changing the value of a variable; the former is visible through all references to that object, the latter only affects that particular variable.

For this to work, the application's `_db_object` and the view's `db_connector` must refer to the same object at all times.

There are essentially two solutions:

1. Give `MySQLConnection` a default state, so you can create one immediately to pass along to `View` rather than starting with `None` and modify it later, or
2. Wrap `MySQLConnection` in another object that you can do the same with

Both options have both benefits and drawbacks.